# LEFT JOIN with avoid duplicate from table right

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to make a join between two tables.

In my first table A, i've the the finest granularity and in the second table B it's an aggregate with a less fine granularity.

When i make the left join between A and B i would like to avoid the redundancy of value of the columns from B.

TABLE A

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 | AG1 | X |
| A1 | D2 | AG1 | X |
| A1 | D3 | AG1 | X |
| A2 | D1 | AG1 | X |
| A2 | D2 | AG1 | X |
| A2 | D3 | AG1 | X |

TABLE B

| ID1 | ID2 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| D3 | AG1 | 0 |
| D4 | AG1 | 3000 |

So here, when i make the join on A.ID2 = B.ID1 AND A.ID3 = B.ID2
the result is :

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| A1 | D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| A1 | D3 | AG1 | 0 |
| A2 | D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| A2 | D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| A2 | D3 | AG1 | 0 |

But, i would like this result :

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| A1 | D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| A1 | D3 | AG1 | 0 |
| A2 | D1 | AG1 | NULL |
| A2 | D2 | AG1 | NULL |
| A2 | D3 | AG1 | NULL |

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: Why the rows from 2nd table are joined to the rows with `id1 = 'A1'` and are not to `id1 = 'A2'`? Provide the rule.

Comment: because A1, A2 etc are products which are selling only once time in the Day (D1,D2 etc) by one AG (AG1, AG2 etc) and what is in table B does not concern the products but only Day and AG

Comment: Enumerate rows in table A with partitioning by `ID2,ID3`. Add `AND rownumber = 1` to joining condition.

Comment: Which DB are you using?? mysql or snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

*This is all Snowflake DB related.*

So to paste Akina's answer, using 2 CTE's for the data, and a third to "prep" the `table_a`, it can look like:

```
WITH table_a AS (
    SELECT * FROM  VALUES
        ('A1','D1','AG1','X'),
        ('A1','D2','AG1','X'),
        ('A1','D3','AG1','X'),
        ('A2','D1','AG1','X'),
        ('A2','D2','AG1','X'),
        ('A2','D3','AG1','X')
        t(ID1,ID2,ID3, xtra)
), table_b AS (
    SELECT * FROM  VALUES
        ('D1','AG1',200),
        ('D2','AG1',350),
        ('D3','AG1',0),
        ('D4','AG1',3000)
        t(ID1,ID2, COL1)
), tabla_a_prep AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id2, id3 ORDER BY id1) as rn
    FROM table_a
)
SELECT
    a.id1,
    a.id2,
    a.id3,
    b.col1
FROM tabla_a_prep AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b 
    ON A.ID2 = B.ID1 AND A.ID3 = B.ID2 AND a.rn = 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

giving:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| A1 | D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| A1 | D3 | AG1 | 0 |
| A2 | D1 | AG1 |  |
| A2 | D2 | AG1 |  |
| A2 | D3 | AG1 |  |

another method is to put the ROW_NUMBER into the selection and use a IFF (or CASE) to select or not select the data, which might be cleaner for single values:

```
SELECT
    a.id1,
    a.id2,
    a.id3,
    IFF(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id2, a.id3 ORDER BY a.id1)=1, b.col1, null) as col1
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b 
    ON A.ID2 = B.ID1 AND A.ID3 = B.ID2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

gives the same results:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | D1 | AG1 | 200 |
| A1 | D2 | AG1 | 350 |
| A1 | D3 | AG1 | 0 |
| A2 | D1 | AG1 |  |
| A2 | D2 | AG1 |  |
| A2 | D3 | AG1 |  |